# Is there a way to avoid repeating the type parameters when using a trait?

Tags: scala

Consider this code

```
val map = new HashMap[(String, String), Set[(String, Int, Double, Int)]] 
        with MultiMap[(String, String),     (String, Int, Double, Int)]
```

Is there a way to use the Multimap trait without repeating the type parameters definition?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a *type alias* to cut down on repetition

```
type K = (String, String)
type V = (String, Int, Double, Int)
```

Then your map becomes

```
val map = new HashMap[K, Set[V]] with MultiMap[K, V]
```

However, as a stylistic rule I don't find it a good idea to use the *TupleN* traits so much in code for a few reasons:

- they are harder to refactor (e.g. if you need an extra field)
- it is less obvious what they represent

Considering that the overhead of creating a bespoke class is as little as:

```
case class K(p1: String, p2: String)
```

it's usually worth it!

Comment: I was going to suggest exactly that. On the other hand, maybe the author of question wants to know how not to repeat the second `[K,V]`

Comment: @pedrofurla yes, you are right, but the above is a great workaround